# SelectPdf component not working on live server

Tags: c#, selectpdf

The URL to pdf conversion works and generates a pdf file locally. But when the code is deployed to the server and when I access this functionality through the live site it always displayed 404 error

Comment: You're gonna need to provide some more details about the hosting environment.  For example, if you are using an Azure Web App, you may have issues as SelectPDF requires elevated permissions

Comment: Hosting: Server Intellect